# Dojo ${} and Spring ${} reference conflict

Tags: javascript, spring, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I am integrating a ArcGis feature layer with infoTemplate. But on the same page I have JSTL variables from Spring as well. Due to this dojo variable refernces ${} are not resolving.

Can any one tell me how to fix this.

```
var content2 = '<b>Location</b>: ${LOCATION}'
            + '<br><b>Timing</b>: ${FRIDAY_STATUS}'
            + '<br><b>Friday</b>: ${PUBLIC_HOLIDAY_STATUS}';

    var infoTemplate2 = new InfoTemplate();
    infoTemplate2.setTitle('Customer Care Centre Details');
    //infoTemplate2.setContent(content2);
```

`${LOCATION},  ${FRIDAY_STATUS}, ${PUBLIC_HOLIDAY_STATUS}` has to be resolved by dojo instead of JSTL Spring....

Comment: can you create a js fiddle or sample for it... or add some more details like feature layer creation and binding the info template to it.. then only we will be able to tell you what exactly u missed...

Answer (score 0):

Well, Below is the similar sample what you are trying to achieve above...

```js
 var map, compare, compare2;

      require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/InfoTemplate",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/number",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser",
        "esri/Color",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
        function (
          Map, InfoTemplate, FeatureLayer, SimpleRenderer, SimpleFillSymbol,
          SimpleLineSymbol, dom, number, on, parser, Color
      ) {

          parser.parse();

          map = new Map("mapDiv", {
            basemap: "streets",
            center: [-86.796, 47.13],
            zoom: 7
          });

          var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
          infoTemplate.setTitle("Population in ${NAME}");
          infoTemplate.setContent("<b>2007 :D: </b>${POP2007:compare}<br/>" +
                                  "<b>2007 density: </b>${POP07_SQMI:compare}<br/><br/>" +
                                  "<b>2000: </b>${POP2000:NumberFormat}<br/>" +
                                  "<b>2000 density: </b>${POP00_SQMI:NumberFormat}");

          var counties = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            infoTemplate: infoTemplate,
            outFields: [
              "NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI",
              "POP07_SQMI"
            ]
          });

          counties.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'Michigan'");

          //apply a renderer
          var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new Color([255, 255, 255, 0.35]), 1),
            new Color([109, 146, 155, 0.35]));
          counties.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));

          map.addLayer(counties);

          on(dom.byId("chkT1"), "click", changeInfoTemplate);
          on(dom.byId("chkT2"), "click", changeInfoTemplate);

          dom.byId("chkT1").checked = true;

          compare = function (value, key, data) {
            var result = "", diff, pctChange;

            switch (key) {
              case "POP2007":
                result = value > data.POP2000 ? "images/up.png" : "images/down.png";
                diff = data.POP2007 - data.POP2000;
                pctChange = (diff * 100) / data.POP2000;
                break;

              case "POP07_SQMI":
                result = value > data.POP00_SQMI ? "images/up.png" : "images/down.png";
                diff = data.POP07_SQMI - data.POP00_SQMI;
                pctChange = (diff * 100) / data.POP00_SQMI;
                break;
            }

            return number.format(value) +
                   "&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src='" + result + "'/>" +
                   "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color: " +
                   (pctChange < 0 ? "red" : "green") + ";'>"
                     + number.format(pctChange, { places: 3 }) +
                   "%</span>";
          };

          compare2 = function (value, key, data) {
            var diff = data.POP2007 - data.POP2000;
            var result = diff > 0 ? "images/up.png" : "images/down.png";
            var pctChange = (diff * 100) / data.POP2000;

            return "<img src='" + result + "'/>" +
                   "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color: " +
                   (pctChange < 0 ? "red" : "green") + ";'>"
                     + number.format(pctChange, { places: 3 }) +
                   "%</span>";
          };

          function changeInfoTemplate () {
            console.log("changed");
            map.infoWindow.hide();

            var t1Checked = dom.byId("chkT1").checked;
            var t2Checked = dom.byId("chkT2").checked;
            var templateContent = "";

            if (t1Checked) {
              templateContent = "<b>2007: </b>${POP2007:compare}<br/>" +
                                "<b>2007 density: </b>${POP07_SQMI:compare}<br/><br/>" +
                                "<b>2000: </b>${POP2000:NumberFormat}<br/>" +
                                "<b>2000 density: </b>${POP00_SQMI:NumberFormat}";
            }
            else if (t2Checked) {
              templateContent = "<b>2007: </b>${POP2007}<br/>" +
                                "<b>2007 density: </b>${POP07_SQMI}<br/><br/>" +
                                "<b>2000: </b>${POP2000:NumberFormat}<br/>" +
                                "<b>2000 density: </b>${POP00_SQMI:NumberFormat}<br/><br/>" +
                                "Diff: ${DIFF:compare2}";
            }

            counties.infoTemplate.setContent(templateContent);
          }
        });
```

```css
 html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
     <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<body class="soria">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
         data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true"
         style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">

      <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ExpandoPane"
           data-dojo-props="duration:300, title:'Details', region:'left', maxWidth:'220px', easeIn:'easing.linear', easeOut:'easing.linear'"
           style="width:220px;">
         <p>
          Click a county to view the population change between 2000 and 2007.<br/> <br/>
          <b>Change the info template:</b> Template 1 displays the percentage growth (or decline) in population. The values are color-coded green for population increase and red for decline in population. Template 2 creates a new calculated field called diff that displays the population difference. <br/>
          <input id="chkT1" name="template" type="radio"/>
          <label for="chkT1">Template 1</label>
          <br />
          <input id="chkT2" name="template" type="radio"/>
          <label for="chkT2">Template 2</label>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="mapDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Feel free to shoot your further queries..

Running Sample For it - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_formatInfoWindow

***Hoping this will help you :)***